# No. of files Vs No. of blocks in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am running a singlenode hadoop environment. When I ran `$hadoop fsck /user/root/mydatadir -block`, I really got confused around output it gave:

```
Status: HEALTHY
 Total size:    998562090 B
 Total dirs:    1
 Total files:   50 (Files currently being written: 1)
 Total blocks (validated):      36 (avg. block size 27737835 B) (Total open file                                                         blocks (not validated): 1)
 Minimally replicated blocks:   36 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks:        0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks:       36 (100.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks:         0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor:    2
 Average block replication:     1.0
 Corrupt blocks:                0
 Missing replicas:              72 (200.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes:          1
 Number of racks:               1
```

It says I have written **50 files** and yet it only uses **36 blocks** (I just Ignore the file currently being written).

From my understanding each file uses atleast 1 block even though its size is less than HDFS block size(for me it's 64MB, the default size).i.e, I expect 50 blocks for 50 files. What is wrong with my understanding ?

Answer (score 1):

The files do not require full blocks each.  The concern is overhead of managing them as well as - if you have truly *many* of them-  namenode utilization:

From Hadoop - The Definitive Guide:

> small files do not take up any more disk space than is required to
>   store the raw contents of the file. For example, a 1 MB file stored
>   with a block size of 128 MB uses 1 MB of disk space, not 128 MB.)
>   Hadoop Archives, or HAR files, are a file archiving facility that
>   packs files into HDFS blocks more efficiently, thereby reducing
>   namenode memory usage while still allowing transparent access to
>   files.

However, a single block only contains a single file - unless a specialized input format such as HAR, SequenceFile, or CombineFileIputFormat is used.  Here is some more information  [Small File problem info](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/)

Comment: In that way, multiple files can be there in a single block. Is it correct?

Comment: In my case I didn't use any special formats. I write just files only one thing they maybe smaller than the HDFS block size.

Comment: So in that case each file has its own block - but at least hadoop does not ship 64Meg around for each one, even if small. You will however end up with more mappers, and so a bit more overhead.

Comment: But I wrote 50 files but only 36 block were found to be used.Can u have a look at my question.

Comment: So you did. I think I'm being of limited assistance here to narrow this down.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46142/discussion-between-tom-sebastian-and-javadba)

Comment: @TomSebastian, could you please post the findings here? Were you able to figure out why the file count is higher than the block count.